# Cap of a sphere: measure of how far from a circle it flattens to?

Tags: geometry, spheres

Intuitively, it seems like the closer the cap is to a full hemisphere, the less circle-like it would be but is that true? Could even caps that on, say, the globe of the Earth only extend to the Arctic Circle Be as uncircle-like as a cap that includes the equator? By this I  mean, perhaps the amount you have to cut or deform a small cap is still the same percentage as a large cap?

Comment: Unless the way cuts or other deformation is permitted is defined. I don't know that your Question can be treated by mathematical reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

No, it can never be the same percentage.  Because if we analyze the data of arithmetic and geometry and find out that there is a difference between what you call a sphere and a hemisphere as a cap.  If you have to say the same percentage as a thorn, you will mention it in the question, but if you have to know about a thorn in general, then it is a hemisphere.  There is nothing more to worry about. You have the complete formula.  Even if you have other information, you only need to consider the radius in mathematical practice. Knowing this radius will solve your question completely.  We all know the area of ​​a hemisphere and its formula for its size.  2πr² and ⅔πr³ respectively.
Regards,
Puskar Sikdar!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).